# SetNeedsLayout() causes other views to not update

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

```
func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification)    {
    self.view.setNeedsLayout() /* */

    var info = aNotification.userInfo as NSDictionary

    var kbSize = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey).CGRectValue().size

    if self.containerViewController.frame != mainFrame! {
        self.containerViewController.frame = mainFrame!
    }

    var aRect = self.view.frame as CGRect

    aRect.size.height = aRect.size.height - kbSize.height

    if CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.textField.frame.origin) == false  {

        self.textField.frame.origin.y = aRect.height - 30
    }
}
```

Why does the self.view.setNeedsLayout() function screw up the placement of that textField? It causes the textField to not move. Is the layout updating too late? If so, how can I fix that. I tried self.view.setLayoutIfNeeded() but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is the line when you set textField's frame origin ever called? have you tried setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: How is the textField added to the view? For me it looks like there are some constraints holding it and that's why changing the frame does not work.

Comment: Yes there are constraints added to it. It moves properly if self.view.setNeedsLayout() is not called. That is why I think the layout is occurring too late.

Comment: It's not about timing of the layout. If you are using auto layout, manually setting of the frame won't work. Instead of setting the frame, you have to adjust the auto layout constraint.

Comment: ?? I do not understand why it would work without setNeedsLayout().

Comment: Do you know how I could account for the keyboard in auto layout?